# Can I draw a SRS from weighted survey observations?

Tags: inference

Assume I have public healthcare data that was gathered through a "complex" survey design and has "weightings" for an observation's likelihood.

It seems many R & Python libraries don't support complex survey design analysis, minus [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/survey.pdf) package in R.

If I want to use other libraries and frameworks, can I draw a simple random sample from my weighted data where the probability of being drawn in a SRS is a function of the weightings? Clearly I'll be using less data than is available but will the analysis be biased because of this procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple random sample from *what* exactly? You will never get an SRS from the population unless you actually sample from that population. If you are subsampling from the survey sample, the survey sample is the population. When the survey sample is stratified, there must be an associated post-stratification weight to account for oversampled individuals.

Theoretically, you can use importance sampling to re-weight participants by their post-stratification weight to obtain a subsample with an expected distribution of strata that is consistent with the larger population. You can't call this a simple random sample, however. This technique would be quite inefficient actually. A better way to go is simply weighting whatever analysis you end up performing using the post-stratification weights directly. That's where the `survey` package comes in handy: the `surveyglm` function handles such analyses quite easily.

Comment: "from what exactly" I suppose I thought I could create a SRS from the weighted sample by using the weightings to inform the probability of being added to the SRS. I agree, that in that case it's not a SRS (as it's a sample that been generated from some prior probabilities) but for the purpose of analysis it might allow me to assume it is. The stakes here are quite low, just a school project.

Comment: @TCopple If you sampled with replacement from your weighted sample according to those weights, that would violate independence assumptions once the same individual was sampled more than once.